# asp.net DropDownList Not updating after bind in UserControl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, postback

I am attempting to update the source of a dropdownlist with a datatable. This appears to be successful in debugging the code behind but the list never actually updates to show the bound items. All of the below code is within a usercontrol that is being used as a view within multiview. The multiview is on a page that has a masterpagefile. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

**VB Code Behind:**

```
Public Sub GetSheetNames(strFilePathName As String)
    Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(strFilePathName) + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    Using (MyConnection)



        MyConnection.Open()
        Dim dt As DataTable = MyConnection.GetSchema("Tables")
        Session("sessdtSheetNames") = dt
        ddSheetName.DataSource = Session("sessdtSheetNames")
        ddSheetName.DataValueField = "TABLE_NAME"
        ddSheetName.DataTextField = "TABLE_NAME"
        ddSheetName.DataBind()

    End Using
    upDD.Update()

End Sub
```

**Dropdownlist from ASPX:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDD" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddSheetName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" style="z-index: 1; left: 351px; top: 128px; position: absolute">
</asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```